Primary Care Physician Visits resulting in Hospital Visits - Statistical Measure
I'm looking for some guidance to help with statistical significance for the below problem (which may need to be reframed).
Problem Statement: Are PCP (primary care physician) visits driving more visits to the hospital?
Essentially we want to know if the hospital visit was the result of a referral and that the PCP visit affected a patient's decision.
I have data for both populations (all PCP visits and all hospital visits within our care system ) and can identify if a PCP patient had a subsequent hospital visit. Both samples will be > 30. A couple of things to consider are, not all PCP visits should result in a hospital visit, and not all hospital visits are related to PCP patients.
I liken this to a "marketing" campaign measurement where Event A drives Event B only it's a little different since Event A shouldn't always result in Event B.
Also, I've considered getting a little more specific such as:

Do PCP visits result in Hospital Visits within 10 days, or 5 days?
Are Hospital visits x times more likely when a PCP was seen within x days?

Any suggestions as to how to approach this would be great. I have novice experience with statistics but have a stats text book to research suggestions.

Why not arrange the data in a contingency table and apply one of these tests.  You won't be able to determine if PCP are "driving" hospital visits in so far as a causal relationship is concerned, but you can effectively measure any correlation this way.

Thanks for the suggestions! There way I see it is there are only three groupings:

Hospital Patients w/PCP Visit (or you could say PCP Patients with Hospital Visits).
Hospital Visits only.
PCP visits only.
Would that work in a contingency table? Two of the values would be the same.


Unfortunately, you can not use a 2x2 contingency table, as you only have 3 of the counts, and you can not get the 4th from your data. And it may not make much sense anyway even if you can get it.
What you are missing is the number of people in your care system who did not have any visit (PCP or hospital) during the period. If you had it (?), then you could use a 2x2, and an appropriate test ($\chi^2$, z-test -these 2 are exactly the same-, or Fisher-exact).
What you can do is simply use descriptive statistics (with binomial CI's around them). Look at the proportion of hospital visits which were preceeded by a PVP visit within a certain time period (5, 10, 15 days?). Now, if that proportion is "large", you can infer it played a role in the subsequent hospital visit. Instead if that proportion is quite small, you can infer that it did not play much of a role (or maybe instead even played a negative role: the PCP visit resolved the condition, so no need for follow up visit). Not ideal, but that is the data you have...
There is another possibility, which may be reasonable. You could look at the number of hospital visits as a function of time since the last PCP visit. How many visits 1 day after the PCP visit, 2 days, 3 days... You can pick the granularity you chose; day by day, by 2 or 3 or 5 days increments, week by week, etc. This depends on how many hospital visits follow a PCP visit in a givem time period. You want a granularity which does not have many 0's, or very low counts. Now, you can look at the correlation between # of hospital visits per time period (day, 2 days, week, etc.) as a function of days since the last PCP visit. You can use good old OLS to look at a linear correlation (if there is one). If a previous PCP visit increases the odds of a hospital visit, one would expect a negative slope to the regression (the further in teh pastt the PCP visit is, the less influence it has). If instead the slope is positive, then there would seem to be a negative effect of the PCP visit on subsequent hospital visits. And if the slope is near 0, then you have no evidence of any (linear) effect.
This approach uses time since the PCP visit as a proxy for the direct effect of the PCP visit. It may or may not be a good proxy.
Note also that the relationship may not be linear. If the initial visit to the PCP resolved the condition, then the patient has no reason to go to the hospital soon thereafter. But if that initial PCP visit did not resolve the issue, there could be increased chances for a hospital visit; but that would not be a few days after, but instead many days (weeks?) after. Note also that the scenario could be even more complex. A single PCP visit may not be appropriate trigger; it may instead be a series of PCP visits, within a ~short time period (a few weeks?), which then triggers a visit to the hospital (as, presumably, the condition was not resolved, or maybe even worsened). So instead of the time since the last PCP visit, you may want to look at the number of prior PCP visits in the few weeks/months? since the first hospital visit?
